# Is node_modules directory required on a remote server for React project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I an running a react project locally.  I want to now run from a remote server, is the node_modules directory necessary to have on the server?

Comment: Do you use anything from that directory when you run it on the server? Simpler answer: remove it and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are dependencies with particular node modules, of course, yes. Try to remove the folder and run your app. If there are errors, try to 'npm install' and run again. If it works, you  need to include node modules folder.

Comment: thanks, right I don't know much about node, and wasn't sure if everything just gets imported, from the directory or something.  anyway, the answer is, yes it is required, thanks!